# CAS 5.2.0 How to configure cas in a way so that it listen to HTTP?

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, cas

There is a load balancer in between the user and the CAS. The load balancer will check allow the SSL certificate. But from the load balancer to the CAS the connection will be HTTP.

How to configure cas in a way so that it listen to HTTP?

I have tried this in my cas.properties but didn't solve my problem:

```
cas.server.httpProxy.enabled=true
cas.server.httpProxy.secure=false ## changed from True
cas.server.httpProxy.protocol=AJP/1.3
cas.server.httpProxy.scheme=http ## changed to http
cas.server.httpProxy.redirectPort=8080
cas.server.httpProxy.proxyPort=8080
cas.server.httpProxy.attributes.attributeName=attributeValue
```

I do have the warning:
"Non-secure Connection You are currently accessing CAS over a non-secure connection. Single Sign On WILL NOT WORK. In order to have single sign on work, you MUST log in over HTTPS." but the warning still remains.
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#http-proxying

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
cas.server.http.port=8080
cas.server.http.protocol=org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol
cas.server.http.enabled=true
```